# POSTing to a Single Item vs. Collection (REST API)

Tags: rest, post

Say I have a REST API with endpoint `/api/users/`. POSTing a user to that endpoint would create a new user and add it to the existing collection, give the user a unique ID so that you can work with it. If I make a `GET /api/users/1`, this should return me the created user with id: 1. My question is what should be the case for POSTing to a single item instead. For POSTing to a collection, you should return `201 Created` if the resource was created, or a `409 Conflict` if the resource already exists. What is the best practice for POSTing to a single resource ? Should it return a `405 Method Not Allowed`, as you shouldn't be allowed to POST to a single resource or should it return a `404 Not Found` as described [here](http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, at the moment a request is received, a resource (regardless of the concept that it represents) does not support a particular method (POST), the correct response to return is `405`

> The 405 (Method Not Allowed) status code indicates that the method received in the request-line is known by the origin server but not supported by the target resource.  The origin server MUST generate an Allow header field in a 405 response containing a list of the target resource's currently supported methods.

The HTTP Specification includes a method ([OPTIONS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.7)) and response headers ([Allow](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.4.1)) that enable a client to interrogate a server to discover what methods are permitted.  [Adoption might be lacking](http://zacstewart.com/2012/04/14/http-options-method.html), although I suppose [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) changes that.

Note: there are use cases where POST to a singular resource is a reasonable option (consider how you would define the protocol to [star a responsitory](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/starring/#star-a-repository) in an api where HTML was your hypermedia format).  In that case, you should choose the appropriate success code (200, 201, 204...), assuming things went well, of course.

Comment: Perhaps I worded my question ambiguously but I mean to ask if a POST should be supported for posting to a specific item (eg. `/api/users/12345`) and have it return `404`/`409`. Is that the best practice or should I just not support it at all, and return a `405 Method Not Allowed` ?

Comment: If /api/users/12345 doesn't support POST, then best practice is to return 405.

Answer (score 0):

If someone tries to POST to a specific item where it should have call PUT to update. In my opinion 404 should be correct return status code, it tells the client that the resource they are looking is unavailable, which means the URL they are hitting isn't correct.

405 method not allowed should be invoked when client is hitting the right URL with wrong method type. suppose you have /api/users/{id} with PUT, but client is using POST.

Comment: What if the resource doesn't exist yet ? They shouldn't be allowed to call PUT on that resource to update.

Comment: Well, PUT is the convention for update calls, in case if resource isn't there the PUT can return 204 No Content